# Insert datetime with milliseconds into MSSQL database using ColdFusion

Tags: sql-server, datetime, coldfusion, odbc, lucee

Using ColdFusion (Lucee 4.5), I need to insert datetime values that include milliseconds into my MSSQL database. I'm creating a UTC datetime value like this:

```
nowUTC = dateConvert("Local2UTC", now());
nowODBC = createODBCDateTime(nowUTC);
```

then I use the following SQL code to insert:

```
insert into tbl (theTime) values (#nowODBC#)
```

However, this method doesn't include milliseconds. The values inserted into the db look like this:

```
2015-10-26 02:14:07.000
```

The last 3 digits after the `.` (period) at the end is MSSQL's fraction of a second notation (1/300), which is always `.000`

How can I include milliseconds or a fraction of a second?  `1/300` is fine.

Comment: What is the type of the column `theTime`? SQL Server `datetime` only holds time to 1/300 of a second. `DATETIME2` defaults to second resolution, but can be specified to millisecond, `datetime2(3)`.

Comment: I'm using datetime... I just looked into it and yes, I probably need to use datetime2, but I don't think ColdFusion (or Lucee in my case) is sending milliseconds to the db.

Comment: WARNING! I tried converting to datetime2, but the jtds odbc driver does not support it, and so my dates were off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot test with Lucee at the moment, but I suspect the problem is not using `cfqueryparam`. The results are the same under CF11. To insert the date and time, *including* milliseconds, use cfqueryparam with type *timestamp*, not createODBCDateTime:

```
<cfquery ....>
   INSERT INTO tbl (theTime) 
   VALUES 
   ( 
     <cfqueryparam value="#nowUTC#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
   )
</cfquery>
```

**Update:**

As [Redtopia mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354622/insert-datetime-with-milliseconds-into-mssql-database-using-coldfusion/33357492?noredirect=1#comment54556530_33357492), the cfscript version would be `addParam()`:

```
query.addParam(name="theTime"
                , value=nowUTC
                , cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp"
              );
```

Comment: I will test this today... I think you're right. At some point (maybe CF9) I quit using cfqueryparam with dates, probably because I was also using CreateODBCDateTime(). I guess it makes sense that you wouldn't need CreatedODBCDateTime() when using cfqueryparam.

Comment: I have not used CreateODBCDateTime in a while, but I *think* the millisecond are there, but are not inserted unless using cfqueryparam with `cf_sql_timestamp`. While you should not need CreateODBCDateTime, I just remembered [Adobe did some wacky things with UTC dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534490/how-to-get-datecompare-to-behave-in-coldfusion-10/32546195#32546195). So if this is existing code, do some testing to make sure the end results are as expected. Hopefully Lucee's implementation is more sane ;-)

Comment: Just tested it and it works without using `CreateODBCDateTime()` and `cfqueryparam`, or `query.addParam(name="theDate", value=nowUTC, cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp")`

Comment: Cool. I was not sure if you were using cfml or cfscript. I will add the latter to the above for greater visibility.

Answer (score 4):

Try directing the query to use one of the native sql server functions for current timestamp including millisecond, this will vary depending on which version of MS SQL you are running. See [GETDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383(v=sql.105).aspx) and [GETUTCDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

You may find something like this is what you want:

```
insert into tbl (theTime) values (GETUTCDATE())
```

*example:*

```
GETUTCDATE() = 2015-10-27 20:10:02.047
```

Comment: Yes, using database functions would work as well. @Redtopia - Though generally it is best to use one or the other. Using both can cause problems if the CF and database are on different servers.

Comment: I second Leigh's comment - if you are concerned about milliseconds you don't want to have a mix - if the time gets off between the 2 servers just a little you will have issues. You want a single source for time - and synch it to a time server as well. Depending on your ver. of Windows server this may be setup automatically for you. But it's pretty easy either way.

Comment: Makes sense... Whether I'm generating times from the app layer, or the db layer, I'm going to run into sync issues in a distributed environment.

Comment: Again, `getdate` only has 1/300 of a second resolution. `SYSDATETIME` returns a `datetime(7)` with up to 100 ns accuracy. Actual accuracy controlled by what windows provides. See remarks: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Yes, I understand. I don't actually need the precision to 1/1000... 1/300 will do. The jtds odbc driver doesn't support datetime2, so I'm better off having it rounded to 1/300.